# Why does Geralt hate storms?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am a decent way into the Witcher 3, having just completed most of the Bloody Baron's questline to find his wife, save for going back to the Bog to try and rescue here. I'm hoping to avoid any major spoilers of this game, but anything from the previous two is fine, since I haven't played them anyway and have no intention of doing so.

Every once and a while, when a storm rolls in, Geralt makes an almost angry remark:

> Damn, a storm is coming in.

Does Geralt just hate storms as anyone might, or is there a specific lore-based reason as to why?

Comment: What do you prefer when going outside? Some nice breeze and sunshine or buckets of water pouring down on you while blowing your feet off the ground...

Comment: @Jutschge The man gobbles down raw meat with no complaint yet he's inconvenienced by a storm? I don't quite understand the downvotes either; having not played the other games, I am not sure if there's a lore reason for him hating storms.

Comment: @Jutschge I'm also not a for-hire cat-like merc carrying two swords around, am i?

Comment: I didn't vote on the question but I understand the downvotes. It's a lore question (often not too popular) and well... who needs a reason to hate storms if they're outside?

Comment: @Jutschge I can't imagine for the life of me why lore questions are disliked, when Skyrim lore questions are voted upwards 10s of times. But fine.

Comment: I think the problem is less the lore and more the common sense. You don't need a reason to dislike rain, a lot of people do. It would be much more interesting to ask why somebody *likes* it instead. You may as well ask "*Why does Geralt grunt whenever he's hit? Does he hate pain?*" It's just a weird question to ask.

Comment: @Nolonar Yes of course common sense plays into it, I'm not so thick skulled that i wonder why people dislike rain. However, with as complex a character as Geralt is, and the world he inhabits, there's a distinct possibility that something in his past affects his feelings towards storms, similar to his attitude on portals.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf one of the books for the Witcher is titled [*Season of Storms*](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Season_of_Storms).  I thought maybe there was a connection between the book and what Geralt says but having never read the book though, I couldn't tell you for sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in [this GameInformer interview](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2015/05/12/cd-projekt-explains-the-witcher-3s-ever-changing-weather-with-exclusive-screenshots.aspx) with CD Projekt Red, the weather (and Geralt's reactions) are a way to make the game world seem more realistic. Geralt dislikes rain as would any person walking or riding a horse around for a living would.

> I think it's really important – it adds a lot to the believability of the world. We were able to create moments in the game like you get in life: You look at the sky and think, "Damn, it's gonna rain, I need to find shelter and meditate till morning."

Similar to the interactions of party members in FFXV, Geralt's reactions to the world around him make him seem more human and believable rather than just a coded entity.

Comment: See, this is all I wanted to know. If there was an in game reason based on the previous games, then that's one thing. But if it's just to make the game more immersive, that's fine. I see no reason for the downvotes, but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Although the developers have stated that Geralt is merely commenting the weather, there could be a link to the books. Minor spoilers follow! In Baptism of Fire, after being treated for an injury, Geralt is experiencing some lingering joint pain. He asks a surgeon later if there's anything that could be done about it, but the reply is "Unfortunately nothing. You'll continue to predict rainy weather unerringly for a long time to come", suggesting that Geralt's joint will ache when it's about to rain.